# Cómo abrir Xampp en ubuntu 20.10 sin que abra la terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Este es mi archivo .desktop que está en /usr/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Xampp Control Panel
GenericName=Services
Exec=/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64 --launch-or-new-window
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=WebServices;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

ya cambien la línea exec por estos intentos:

```
Exec=/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Exec=sudo ./opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Exec=/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run %F
```

pero en todas me abre la terminal, me pide contraseña y luego no hay problema.

estos son los permisos de mi xampp_control_panel.desktop:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo solucione de esta manera:

creé un archivo .sh de bash con el comando para ejecutar el administrador de xampp con el siguiente comando en una terminal:

```
cat > /escritorio/xampp/xampp.sh
echo <contraseña SU> | sudo -S /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

(el archivo no debe estar en el escritorio sino no funciona)

Luego debes configurar el archivo para que pueda ejecutarse, lo haces con clic derecho -> propiedades -> permisos y debes marcar la casilla de "permitir ejecutar el archivo como un programa".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego debes entrar a las preferencias del administrador de archivos de linux.
[image: aqui se encuentra la opcion de preferencias]

En la pestaña comportamiento en el apartado de archivos de texto ejecutables debes seleccionar la opción que dice ejecutarlos.
[image: asi debe quedar configurado]

De esa manera al hacer doble clic sobre el archivo se abrirá el administrador de xampp.